# Message persistence system design question

Tags: architecture, message-queue, system-design

guys, I have an application that does the following the shop owner posts a piece data on the website and these messages should be sent to all the users who are using the website; messages should be displayed like in a bulletin board. So my requirement is that messages should be persistent on the website even after the user reloads the page or re-opens the page. I have thought of several ideas but getting confused.

1. use socket.io for real-time pushing of messages -- however, messages are not persisted.
2. Use Redis for message caching and also simultaneously update in my MongoDB
3. use something like a Kafka or Rabbitmq but I'm completely clueless on how to implement it

What approach should I choose, please guide me.

I'm using a MERN stack

Comment: It sounds like a real time + historical messages. If my assumption is right, then you must persist the message and have some kind of poll mechanism from your browser session to update messages in your bulletin board. Did you thought about how long your would show messages in individual users bulletin board or what if user do not want to see a specific message (since they have noticed it before) ?

Comment: They would be still visible i guess